# How to configure auto-generated outputs?

Tags: aws-cdk

When deploying resources with AWS CDK (Java), I get some outputs generated automatically. Not sure why, but they are created with the prefix "ExportsOutputRef" and some export names. However, those are not declared in my code.

Would it be possible to disable or configure the creation of these "automagic" outputs? Is this documented somewhere?

This screenshot presents my declared outputs preceded by the "auto" ones
[image: demostration of the issue]

Comment: Outputs and exports are not magic, they are explicitly configured in your code or in the code of the constructs you use. And wether you can disable or change them also depends on that code.

Comment: @luk2302 that's not necessarily right, they are usually defined in the core CDK code, not in any constructs. The constructs use them implicitly when something is being references across stacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CDK automatically creates a CloudFormation [stack output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#stack-outputs) prefixed with `ExportsOutputRef` or `ExportsOutputFnGetAtt` when it detects a [cross-stack reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#accessing-resources-in-a-different-stack) to a resource.

These automatic references are CDK implementation details with no opt-out.

I hesitate even to mention it, but if you really don't want to accept the artefact the CDK has synthesized for you, the CDK's [escape hatch syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html) lets you make arbitrary modifications to the CloudFormation template.  While definitely not recommended, you could remove the unwanted references with [tryRemoveChild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/constructs.Node.html).

Comment: Thank you, that is great to know. No need to remove it, just wondering where that came from.